# How to improve my knee impact in clinching

Tags: kicking, muay-thai, striking

In my first match I was doing pretty good in clinching but my knees were too frequent and not powerful. I've been working on a bag pretty much every chance i get and do about 50-100 knees after every training but I wanted to know if there's any other kind of training that would help me improve the impact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as everyone is silent, I'll add my two cents.

When using your knees to hit your opponent's body, you may go in two ways:

> Your opponent is much stronger than you.

You cannot pull his body towards you to make it more vulnerable to your knees. In such situations, frequent and light hits may be an option - at least it will complicate your opponent's attacks. But in general, it is a very bad situation (i.e., clinching with a much stronger opponent) - try to avoid it at any cost.

> Your opponent is as strong as you, or less stronger.

You can pull his body towards you while clinching. In this case, you may use a two-step tactic (this is only a single example from the hoard of other moves).

1. Step-back with back-leg, then step-side with front-leg and turn - you may know this move as "twister". With the second step you should pull your opponent, using both your strength and move.
2. As your opponent is bent forward (remember your front-leg is now on the side and has good amplitude potential?), incline your body back with your front-leg kneeing your opponent. Inclining your body back matters - in fact, you shouldn't bend a hitting leg much - the main point here is your upper body move. Along with this move, try to grab your opponent closer to you.

Main point in heavy knees - inclining (or pulling) your upper-body back along with throwing the knee using your weight.

Answer (score 2):

I'd work on two areas.

---

> 1. The **explosiveness** of the knee during the kick

How hard you can knee someone depends on how strong your oblique muscles are, and how well they work with your hip rotation.

Do a lot of crunches either with bodyweight or with resistance bands.

Instead of usual knee kicks on the sandbag, practice jumping knee kicks, focusing on contracting your obliques and exploding upwards and outwards.

---

> 2. The **target**

Most people knee with the front of the knee, with the patella. I find using the side of the knee to be more effective. Instead of aiming for the opponent's stomach, go for a more vulnerable spot. That's the floating rib.